# translate and transform not working on Mozilla but working on other browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, transform, css-transitions

I have made a site where a grid of images are animated by adding / removing css classes.  Each of the css classes have a `transition duration` (shorthand) applied, and the classes are added in such a way so that the image is given a starting position and then (after a fake `setTimeout`) ending position, so that they animate to the position.

**[Here is the hosted page](http://www.willynolan.com/test)**  (www.willynolan.com/test)

What is strange is that this works on every browser except firefox, even though firefox was supposed to support the css `transition` and `transform` property before all the other browsers.  In fact, autoprefixer doesn't even reccomend prefixing those properties.  Even better, the transitions work about 1/2 the time in firefox, even while testing on an older version of firefox.

Instead of posting a fiddle, because the code is somewhat complicated, I hosted the whole page.  You can see by opening in firefox and other browsers the difference.   I did test the `transform` and `transition` properties in jsfiddle, and they did work in firefox so I have no idea what it is.  I will post the HTML/CSS/JS code here.  No errors show up in either Chrome or Firefox's developer tools.

Please note, because I have tested prefixed versions of the same code and looked at browser support, I know adding the `-moz-`prefix will not work. I have already tried this.

**CSS**

```
/**********************************************  Base Styles  *****************************************************/
html, body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding-left: .25em;
}

h1 span {
    color: #999;
}

#menuIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 16;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    margin: .2em .2em 0 .4em;
    background: black url('../media/media/nav.png') center;
}


nav ul {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
}

nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    left: 0;
    margin: .2em;
    top: 2.5em;
    width: 10em;
    z-index: 15;
}
nav ul.clicked {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    left: 0;
    margin: .2em;
    top: 2.5em;
    width: 10em;
    z-index: 15;
}

nav ul.none {
    display: none;
    width: 0;

}

nav li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: .6em 0;
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: white;
}

nav li a:hover, nav li a:focus {
    color: #777;
    -webkit-transition: color 500ms ease-out;
    transition: color 500ms ease-out;
}

nav li a:active {
    color: #444;
}

#mainContainer {
    display: block;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.imageHolder {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56%;
    margin-bottom: .1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

img.loaded {
    display: none;
}



/**********************************************  Next Size Up Styles  ****************************************************************/


@media (min-width: 31.25em) {
    html {
        max-width: 1400px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 2.5em;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 35em) {
    [data-icon]:before {
        display: none;
    }

    footer {
        font-size: .8em;
    }

    footer ul li small, footer ul li small, .footerItem {
        display: inline;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 38.5em) {
    div.imageHolder {
        max-width: 512px;
        padding-bottom: 288px;
    }
    div.imageHolder {
        margin: 0 auto .1em auto;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 512px;
        padding-bottom: 288px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
    footer {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 60em){
    header {
        position: relative;
        height: 5.5em;
        width: 85%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }

    h1 {
        position: relative;
        top: 1.3em;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #menuIcon {
        display: none;
    }

    nav:hover ul, nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3em;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: right;
        background: transparent;
        list-style: none;
    }


    nav ul li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0 .6em;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        line-height: 3em;
    }

    a:link, a:visited {
        color: black;
    }

    #mainContainer {
        margin: 2.5em auto 0 auto;
        padding-left: 1%;
    }


    div.imageHolder {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 33%;
        padding-bottom: 18.7%;
        margin-bottom: .1em;
        margin-right: .1em;
    }

    div.imageContent {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    div img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        margin: 0;
    }

    footer {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}



#overlay {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
}


#largeImage {
    max-width: 75%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
            backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-animation: goBig 700ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
    animation: goBig 700ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
}

/**********************************  Transitions   *******************************************/

.opacityStart {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.opacityEnd {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
            transition: opacity 1s;
}

.scaleXStart {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform:scaleX(0);
        -ms-transform:scaleX(0);
            transform:scaleX(0);
}

.scaleXEnd {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
        -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
            transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
            transition: transform 1s;
}

.scaleYStart {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform:scaleY(0);
        -ms-transform:scaleY(0);
            transform:scaleY(0);
}

.scaleYEnd {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
        -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
            transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
            transition: transform 1s;
}

.translateRightStart {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);
}

.translateRightEnd {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
            transition: transform 1s;
}

.translateLeftStart {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
            transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.translateLeftEnd {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
            transition: transform 1s;
}

.translateYUpStart {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
            transform: translateY(-100%)
}

.translateYUpEnd {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
            transition: transform 1s
}

.translateYDownStart {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%)
}

.translateYDownEnd {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
            transition: transform 1s
}



/**********************************  Animations   *******************************************/



@-webkit-keyframes goBig {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    }
}
@keyframes goBig {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
                transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
                transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue,
        randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
}

var turnObjToArray = function(obj) {
    return [].map.call(obj, function(element) {
        return element;
    });
};

/*  Images  */
var imageArray = [
    {     
        source: 'media/media/test.jpg'
    },
    {     
        source: 'media/media/test.jpg'
    },
    {     
        source: 'media/media/test.jpg'
    },
    {     
        source: 'media/media/test.jpg'
    }
];

shuffle(imageArray);


var imageElements = [];

/*  Turn animating divs into random array for later manipulation    */
var startHolders = shuffle(turnObjToArray(document.querySelectorAll('.imageContent')));

/*  Load first images   */
function startLoader(index) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        startHolders[index].appendChild(this);
        imageElements.push(this);
    };
    image.src = imageArray[index]['source'];
}

(function(){
    for(var i = 0, j = startHolders.length; i < j; i += 1) {
        startLoader(i);
    }
})();



function imageLoader(i) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        imageElements.push(this);
    };
    image.src = imageArray[i]['source'];
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    /*  Preload images    */
    (function preload(){
        for(var i = startHolders.length; i < imageArray.length; i += 1) {
            imageLoader(i);
        }
    })();

    /*  Start animations    */
    var animation = (function () {
        var a = {};
        a.divIndex = 0;
        a.imgIndex = startHolders.length;
        a.animIndex = 0;
        a.run = function() {
            if(!document.querySelector('#overlay')){
                imageElements[a.imgIndex].className = animations[a.animIndex]['start'];
                startHolders[a.divIndex].appendChild(imageElements[a.imgIndex]);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    imageElements[a.imgIndex].className = animations[a.animIndex]['end'];
                    if(++a.divIndex === startHolders.length) a.divIndex = 0;
                    if(++a.imgIndex === imageElements.length) a.imgIndex = 0;
                    if(++a.animIndex === animations.length) a.animIndex = 0;
                }, 0);
            }
        };
        return a;
    })();
    setInterval(animation.run, 1500);


    /*  Create Overlay   */
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if(e.target.tagName == 'IMG' && e.target.id != 'largeImage') {
            var overlay = document.createElement('div');
            overlay.id = 'overlay';
            document.body.appendChild(overlay);
            overlay.addEventListener('click', function(){
                this.remove();
            },false);

            var overImage = new Image();
            overImage.addEventListener('load', function(){
                this.id = 'largeImage';
                if(this.height > window.innerHeight) {
                    this.ratio = window.innerHeight / this.height;
                    this.height = this.height * this.ratio;
                    this.width = this.width * this.ratio;
                }
                if(this.width > window.innerWidth) {
                    this.ratio = window.innerWidth / this.width;
                    this.height = this.height * this.ratio;
                    this.width = this.width * this.ratio;
                }
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var a = document.getElementById('largeImage');
                    centerImage(a);
                }, 30);

                centerImage(this);
                overlay.appendChild(this);
            }, false);
            if(window.innerWidth > 513){
                overImage.src = e.target.src.substr(0, e.target.src.length - 7) + '1024.jpg';
            } else {
                overImage.src = e.target.src;
            }
        }

        function centerImage(theImage) {
            var myDifX = (window.innerWidth - theImage.width) / 2;
            var myDifY = (window.innerHeight - theImage.height) / 2;
            theImage.style.top = myDifY + 'px';
            theImage.style.left = myDifX + 'px';
            return theImage;
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
            if(document.querySelector('#largeImage')){
                centerImage(document.querySelector('#largeImage'));
            }
        },false);

    },false);

    var menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menuIcon');
    var clicked = false;
    menuIcon.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
        clicked = !clicked;
        if(clicked) {
            document.querySelector('nav ul').className = 'clicked';
        } else {
            document.querySelector('nav ul').className = 'none';
        }
    }, false);
});

/*  Animations  */

var opacity = {
    start: 'opacityStart',
    end: 'opacityEnd'
};

var scaleX = {
    start: 'scaleXStart',
    end: 'scaleXEnd'
};

var scaleY = {
    start: 'scaleYStart',
    end: 'scaleYEnd'
};

var translateRight = {
    start: 'translateRightStart',
    end: 'translateRightEnd'
};

var translateLeft = {
    start: 'translateLeftStart',
    end: 'translateLeftEnd'
};

var translateUp = {
    start: 'translateYUpStart',
    end: 'translateYUpEnd'
};

var translateDown = {
    start: 'translateYDownStart',
    end: 'translateYDownEnd'
};


var animations = [
    opacity,
    scaleX,
    scaleY,
    translateRight,
    translateLeft,
    translateUp,
    translateDown
];
shuffle(animations);
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!--[if IE]> <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <article id="mainContainer">
        <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"></div></div>
        <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"></div></div>
        <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"></div></div>
        <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"></div></div>
        <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"></div></div>
        <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"></div></div>
        <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"></div></div>
        <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"></div></div>
        <div class="imageHolder"><div class="imageContent"></div></div>
    </article>
    <script src="scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```